# Routing in ASP.Net core 2 MVC

Tags: c#

I have been working for ~1 year with MVC now but haven't really ever had to look deep into routing and just used the normal Defaults. In a new Application I now need to adjust these and cant figure out how it exactly works.

My Situation
I have an application starting with a View with a List of different Calendars in a DB.
Each of these Calendars should have a url to them like the following:

home/calendarName/weekNumber

--> controller/dynamic string based on name of calendar/dynamic int based on selected week

The issue is that I don't want to create a action for every single CalendarName--> calendar.

Is my Problem understandable?

This is my Startup.cs Code atm:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "test",
                  template: "test",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Name-Of-Calender", id="WeekID_Of_Calendar" });


                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=KalenderListe}/{id?}");
            });
```

This is the URL-Action in the View atm.

```
"@Url.Action("View", "Home", new {KalenderName= kalender.KalenderName,Id= kalender.KalenderId})"
```

If it isn't clear what im trying to do, let me know and I'll adjust it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you can use Attribute routing on action method. Just write the string in your route just like below

`

```
[Route("Home/About")]
   public IActionResult MyAbout()
   {
      return View("About");
   }
   [Route("Home/Contact")]
   public IActionResult MyContact()
   {
      return View("Contact");
   }
```

`

You can also change as you want like

`

```
[Route("About/Home")]
   public IActionResult MyAbout()
   {
      return View("About");
   }
```

`

Comment: This didnt work for me unfortunatly. I have parameters I pass to the action and it writes them into the URL after the Route I typed in on top.

Comment: And another Issue, the Name in the URL is diffrent with each type of kalender. And as mentioned I want that to dynamicly change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing on your action within your home controller.

```
[HttpGet("{calendarName}/{id}")]
public void ActionResult GetCalendar(string calendarName, int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to pass the as a optional query

```
[HttpGet("{calendarName}")]
public void ActionResult GetCalendar(string calendarName, [FromQuery]int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh perfect worked. One question though...If I would wanna leave away the id in the httpget and only display the calendarname, how can I leave the id away? When I just tried to remove the weeknumber this happend --> https://localhost:44306/KalenderTool?Id=1

Comment: Sorry. not sure I understand. You want want id to be optional?

Comment: nono Im just asking how I could leave the ID away completly but still pass it as a parameter. So hide it i guess

Comment: If you change the route to just `{calendarName}`, but keep id as a parameter, it should bind to query parameters (`?id=x`). You can put `[FromQuery]` in front to make sure it only binds to the query too. Alternatively, you could have the route be `{calenderName}/{id?}`, and your action should be hit whether you pass `id` or not

Comment: the FromQuery thing is what im looking for. Where do I have to put it?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: displays id=1 from url action in view

Comment: You should be able to remove the id from your view: `@Url.Action("View", "Home", new {KalenderName= kalender.KalenderName})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196001/discussion-between-esg-and-mischa-morf).